# Is Pikachu on a diet?

Tags: pokemon

I noticed that Pikachu evolved a little over time.
I wonder why he changed his form so much, so [I'm a bit worried about Pikachu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGF8P.png).
[image]

Comment: And I just burst out laughing lol XD

Comment: Does Pikachu eat food?

Comment: @kuwaly: At least in the anime, Rocko is often seen cooking meals, also for Pikachu.

Comment: As time passes, animation level and quality becomes better and better!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's most likely a matter of different character designers over the different generations of the franchise. The original design was created by [Game Freak's (original game's designers) character development team and finalized by artist Ken Sugimori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pikachu#Concept_and_design). The [games themselves had changes in Pikachu's designs](http://bulbanews.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_sprites,_art_evolve_over_the_years), which were in turn mirrored by the anime:

[image] "Green and Red", 1996

[image] "Blue", 1996

[image] "Yellow", 1998

[image] "Gold", 1999

[image] "Ruby and Sapphire", 2002

[image] "Diamond and Pearl", 2006

[image] "Platinum", 2008

[image] "HeartGold and SoulSilver", 2009

Ken Sugimori is also one of the character designers for the first [TV series from 1997](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=270). In 2002, [Pokemon Advance](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1873) had Sayuri Ichiishi as the character designer. And in 2006, [Pocket Monsters](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=6836) and 2010's [Black and White](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=11685) has Toshiya Yamada in charge of character designs.

[image] from the "Advance" generation

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's Pikachu losing weight but a reasonable design alteration. The head can move realistically instead of just being glued to the body, the feet are better defined, and the arms are more expressive. Even the ears have some flexibility. If anything, the tail looks bigger.